# Where is the gap between these Bootstrap buttons coming from?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

These [buttons](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#examples) have a gap between them. I'm unable to recreate that. Using the inspector tool I can't figure out where that gap is coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's coming from the `font-size` of the container. This is happening because the buttons themselves are set to display as `inline-block`, which means they're inline with the text and treated very similarly. As there's a new line between each element in the markup, a space appears (as this is how the HTML specification tells browsers how to handle new lines).

We can demonstrate this ourselves with the same display property:

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button>Bar</button>
```

If we increase the `font-size` of the `body` (the container for these buttons in this example), the size of the space will increase:

```css
body {
  font-size: 72px;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button>Bar</button>
```

We can remove the gap completely by giving the container a `font-size` of 0:

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<button>Foo</button>
<button>Bar</button>
```

See also: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Ah! Makes sense -- turns out the reason I was getting no gap is because Jade automatically minifies everything so that the buttons were not on separate lines unless you explicitly separate them. Thanks!